# Standardising Results Between Experimental Groups

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data on five experiments, which vary slightly, and I would like to find a way of standardizing results between experiments to develop a “standard result.” This will be a value I can multiply each result by to make them comparable.
The way I have gone about this is there are individuals in more than one experimental group (assuming being in more than one group doesn’t affect results).

I am assuming the results of individuals in more than one experiment are only different because of the slight differences between experiments and so by calculating a conversion factor for each experiment that makes the average of the individuals results in more than one experiment the same that can translate results into a standard result.

The problem I am experiencing is at the end of the process most of my conversion factors are less than 1. However, I was expecting to get roughly an even number of values greater than 1 and less than 1 as I am sort of averaging out the results.

My procedure and MSQL code is below:

1. Get data by experiment and by individual and exclude all individual’s data that is only in 1 experiment.

```
    SELECT ExperimentID, 
       IndividualID, 
    INTO Z1_IndivByExperiment
    FROM Results
    GROUP BY ExperimentID, 
         IndividualID

    SELECT IndividualID, 
       COUNT(ExperimentID) AS ExperimentCount
    INTO Z2_MultiExperIndiv
    FROM Z1_IndivByExperiment
    GROUP BY IndividualID 
    HAVING COUNT(ExperimentID) > 1
    ORDER BY ExperimentCount DESC
```

2. Create two tables:
   i)  Summaries results by individual (an individual can have multiple results per experiment) and experiment.
   ii) Summaries results by individual

```
    SELECT ExperimentID,
       IndividualID, 
       SUM(Results.Result) AS Result_sum, 
       SUM(Results.ResultsCount) AS ResultCount_sum
    INTO Z3_MultiExperIndiv_Results
    FROM Results INNER JOIN
         Z2_MultiExperIndiv ON Results.IndividualID = 
    Z2_MultiExperIndiv.IndividualID
    GROUP BY ExperimentID,
         IndividualID

    SELECT 'Standard' AS Experiment
       IndividualID, 
       SUM(Result_sum) AS ResultIndiv_sum, 
       SUM(ResultCount_sum) AS ResultCountIndiv_sum
    into Z4_MultiExperIndiv_Stand
    FROM Z3_MultiExperIndiv_Results 
    GROUP BY IndividualID
```

3. Link the two tables created in step 2 by individual summing results from table 1 and table 2 by experiment. I am hoping this provides two sets of results for individuals on the experiment in question and results for individuals who were part of the experiment in question from other experiments were.

```
    SELECT Z4_MultiExperIndiv_Stand.ExperimentID AS ExperimentID1, 
       Z3_MultiExperIndiv_Results.ExperimentID AS ExperimentID2, 
           SUM(Z4_MultiExperIndiv_Stand.ResultIndiv_sum - 
    Z3_MultiExperIndiv_Results.Result_sum) AS Results1, 
       SUM(Z4_MultiExperIndiv_Stand.ResultCountIndiv_sum - 
    Z3_MultiExperIndiv_Results.ResultCount_sum) AS ResultCount1, 
           SUM(Z3_MultiExperIndiv_Results.Result_sum) AS Results 2, 
       SUM(Z3_MultiExperIndiv_Results.ResultCount_sum) AS ResultCount2
    into Z5_StandardConversion_data
    FROM Z3_MultiExperIndiv_Results INNER JOIN
         Z4_MultiExperIndiv_Stand ON Z3_MultiExperIndiv_Results.IndividualID = 
    Z4_MultiExperIndiv_Stand.IndividualID
    GROUP BY Z4_MultiExperIndiv_Stand.IndividualId,
         Z3_MultiExperIndiv_Results.IndividualId
```

4. Then I divide results for each set of results by number of results and divide one by the other to get my conversion to standard number for each experiment.

```
    SELECT ExperimentID1, 
       ExperimentID2, 
       Results1, 
       ResultCount1, 
       Results2, 
       ResultCount2, 
       Results1 / ResultCount1 AS Result1_avg, 
       Results2 / ResultCount2 AS Result2_avg, 
    (ResultCount2 * Results1) / (ResultCount1 * Results2) AS Conversion
    FROM Z5_StandardConversion_data
```

Sample input data:

[image]

Sample Output:

[image]

Comment: Please post some example data and expected results so people can see what you are trying to accomplish and where the figures differ.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Is your sample output what you are getting or what you are expecting? And please ensure both sets of data are in your question.

Comment: The sample output is what I am getting and I am unsure why they are all under 1. I thought there should be a mix of greater than and less than 1.

Comment: Sorry how do I put a table in rather than image of table?

Comment: Google is your friend: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220127/how-to-make-tables-in-good-format-in-asking-questions-here-which-is-understanda